# Get everything inside <a></a> regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code. I am trying to get everything inside the "a" tags. At the moment it is working. I am getting “first” and “second” as an output. opening "a" tag and closing "a" tag are in the same line.

```
$v = 'this is test 
<a href="products.html">first</a> 
<a>second</a;
preg_match_all("#<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>#", $v, $foo);
echo implode("\n", $foo[1]);
```

But if I write the following way,

```
$v = '<a href="products.html">first
</a> 
preg_match_all("#<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>#", $v, $foo);
echo implode("\n", $foo[1])';
```

here i moved the closing "a" tag to the second line and now It's not giving me any output. Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The same link. Every time.

Comment: try to use simple_html_dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ Working with regex to parse html is not well solution.

Comment: @JezenThomas: Someday we shall be redeemed and the evil will be cast out.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php look at PCRE_MULTILINE

Comment: @Mahakala, PCRE_MULTILINE is not relevant.  It is PCRE_DOTALL.

Comment: Can SO write a regex to filter out questions about parsing HTML with regex, and automatically forward them to that question in the first comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the problem you are having, it is because you need to enable the single line option (`s`):

```
preg_match_all("#<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>#s", $v, $foo);
```

Otherwise `.` does not match a line break.

Explanation of the option [from the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.

But you probably would be better off not using a regex.  [See this question for other approaches in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php/3577662#3577662).

Comment: +1 for actually providing a solution. That old “Don’t use regex for parsing HTML!” link is getting very tired.

Comment: Can you please tell me what that "s" is for?. Thanks. I used it and it works perfect.